# "Query is not understandable" - Full text searching where field types have changed

Tags: full-text-search, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, full-text-indexing

A client have a long lived IBM Notes application where someone along the line changed the type of a field from number to text.

So, now when we're trying to do an FT search like: [myField] = "1234" receive the error message: "Query is not understandable".

If I do: [myField] = 1234 it works but won't return any hits. Even though there's a document where myField = "1234".

The field is of type text in the design.

I've created a new view for testing, only allowing documents from one form.

Deleted the full text index (even on the file system)
updall -X
Fixup -r
Created full text index

In my test view I've got one column that shows if the field content being searched is of type text @IsText(myField) and all rows shows: 1 (so it's field content must be text)

None of the above worked so I created a new database copy locally.
Same problem.

Created an entirely new database (for testing only), form, view and full text index and that works.

Feels like the existing database design somewhere stores the old field type...

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

/J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Datatypes and field names are stored in the UNK table. There is just one entry per field name, so it's critical not to use the same field name more than once in an application with different datatypes.

You need to rebuild the UNK table, as I blogged here http://www.intec.co.uk/full-text-search-musings/

Note, it **must** be an offline compact, as Duffbert says here http://www.duffbert.com/duffbert/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TDUF-5SMHV4. If anyone is in the database when you do the compact, it will fail and the UNK table will not be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Links are useful, but if you don't want to remove data from documents - for me such steps worked (and there was no need in removing fields from forms in designer):

- Run from designer with manager access with such code inside

  ```
  Sub Initialize  
  Dim s As New NotesSession
  Dim db As NotesDatabase
  Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
  Dim doc As NotesDocument
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
  Dim noteid As String
  Dim nextnoteid As string
  Dim itemArr As Variant
  Dim NeedSave As Boolean

  Const ITEM_NAME = "itemName1|itemName2"

  itemArr = Split( ITEM_NAME, "|" )
  'погромист-кун не должен забывать про наличие итемов в формах...
  Set db = s.Currentdatabase  
  Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False) 
  nc.SelectForms = true
  Call nc.BuildCollection
  noteid = nc.Getfirstnoteid()
  For i =  1 To nc.Count
      Set doc = db.Getdocumentbyid( noteid )
      noteid = nc.Getnextnoteid( noteid )
      NeedSave = false
      ForAll IA In itemArr
          If doc.Hasitem( IA ) Then
              Call doc.Removeitem( IA )
              NeedSave = true
          End If
      End ForAll
      If NeedSave Then
          Call doc.Save( True, False )
      End If
      Print CStr( i ) & "\" & CStr( nc.Count )
  Next    

  End Sub
  ```
- Remove database index
- Run from administrator command lo compact database.nsf -c , like mentioned in links above
- Create index