# How can I get a Lotus Notes search formula to work for fieldnames that contain underscores?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I tried a search formula in xpages using a field name containing underscores, and I got syntax errors.

My search is very very easy

```
FIELD HR_FullName CONTAINS <value> or

FIELD HR_FullName CONTAINS Bryan
```

This says that query is not understandable. In fact, any field with an "_" in it gives query is not understandable. If I use a field without an underscore then it works.

I deleted the index and recreated it, but it still had this problem.

Am I going crazy or doing something wrong????

Yes the question was answered. The problem was that I had changed the definition of a field (or more than one) and the UNK table only lists one entry for field name, so when you try to do a search you can get this error. Knut added in a link to someone who had a similar issue.

The link had a way to rebuild the UNK table. My solution was just to replicate the db locally, delete the server version, and re replicate up. That fixed it.

Comment: Tested it: using fieldnames with underscore works in my 901 client. Which versions do you run here?

Comment: I am using 9.0.1 as well. I rebooted my client. Then I created a local copy of the database. That worked. So something must be corrupt in the DB, I assume. So sorry for the false alarm, still very frustrating. Oh and I did recreate the Full-Text index on the db on the server.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17087389/2065611 It shows you how to recreate full text index and UNK table. This helps if one field have had different data types.

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense. It was easier for me to make a local replica, delete server replica, and then re-replicate up to the server. Thank you very much Knut and Oliver.

Comment: So your question was answered, Bryan? Please add an answer then :-)